# if(temp_similarity[k]==similarity[l]): ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, if-statement

I am trying to compare the 2 values from the indexes of two different numpy arrays as below:

```py
if(temp_similarity[k]==similarity[l]):
    sum = sum+probabilities_train[l]
    break
```

but i found the following error?

```
if(temp_similarity[k]==similarity[l]):

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous.
            Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Please help me in this regards???

Comment: What is the particular problem you're having? The error message is quite clear about things you could try.

Comment: Yeah i have figured out the solution. Thanks!